# How to create marble wave pattern and animate it?

Tags: animation, texturing, materials

How to create marble wave pattern and animate it?

I tried noise texture and it did not work.

[image]

Comment: It's difficult beyond possibility to reproduce a pattern like this, exactly, procedurally. Therefore you need to describe the pattern in some way so we know what you're after. How about "colored oil stain texture"? Or maybe it's supposed to be more like a marble or Jupiter atmosphere?

Comment: Marble it is! Thank you!

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady looks like curl noise to me...